# Error Formulating Crash Report: dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, apple-m1

after upgrading Flutter to 3.7.1, from the Ios emulator "**Error Formulating Crash Report: I started getting the dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed**” error. Can you help on the subject?

MacBook Air M1
macOS Venture 13.2
Xcode 14.2

Comment: did you fix this? I am also getting the same issue